# Backward compatibility of Webservice operation output messages in case of a xsd choice extension

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I have a question about backward compatibility of a Webservice interface in context of choices in output message. Couldn't really find an answer to that.

Let's assume I have a Webservice with an operation "getData" which has the following response message (this is V1 of the Webservice). The response message includes a choice element which gives back either the payload of "Instruction" or "KeyTranslation". This V1 WSDL is used by various consumer which are generating the java bindings and rolling out the application in production.

```
<xsd:complexType name="GetInstructionListResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ContinueInfo" type="tns:ContinueInfo" form="qualified" />
        <xsd:element name="ResultLength" type="xsd:integer" form="qualified" />
        <xsd:element name="Payload">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="DataObjectList1" type="tns:Instruction" form="qualified" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="50" />
                <xsd:element name="DataObjectList2" type="tns:KeyTranslation" form="qualified" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="50" />
            </xsd:choice>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ReturnCodeList" type="tns:ReturnCodeList" form="qualified" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Description: List of error descriptions</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

As a provider of this interface we would introduce now a third choice element "Advise" after the rollout of V1.

```
    <xsd:complexType name="GetInstructionListResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ContinueInfo" type="tns:ContinueInfo" form="qualified" />
        <xsd:element name="ResultLength" type="xsd:integer" form="qualified" />
        <xsd:element name="Payload">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="DataObjectList1" type="tns:Instruction" form="qualified" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="50" />
                <xsd:element name="DataObjectList2" type="tns:KeyTranslation" form="qualified" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="50" />
                <xsd:element name="DataObjectList2" type="tns:Advice" form="qualified" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="50" />
            </xsd:choice>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ReturnCodeList" type="tns:ReturnCodeList" form="qualified" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Description: List of error descriptions</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Question is now, is this change in the output message a breaking change, i.e does an existing consumer (working with V1 which doesn't require the new choice element) has to do anything (e.g. to regenerate the java bindings, any marshalling problems?) in case we would replace as a provider the V1 WSDL provider interface with this extended response structure or would that be transparent for him as long he doesn't require the third choice element in its processing?

Comment: Choices are not that extensible; as an example, JAXB versions without a custom binding file will create funky named get/set for the choice, depending on what's in the choice. So the problem may be that even after accepting the change and recreating the code (using xjc) you will get classes that break the code (again, unless you use custom bindings). Your approach with enum is correct. Another mechanism that achieves the same, better in terms of default bindings, is to consider substitution groups instead of choices.

Comment: thx for the answer and additional point. considering substiution group i will check it out. i have to add that the webservice facade is backed by ibm zos cobol based service implementation. the current wsdl2cobol compiler is somewhat limited in its wsdl feature richness. from a deployment point of view our consumers will use the wsdl at compile time and not runtime. Any new compile and deployment will include the passing of two indepentent test environemnt stages.

Comment: Just curious, is this choice due to REDEFINES?

Comment: I suppose you mean COBOL redefines on copybooks? The answers is Yes and No. In certain areas we will use choices to enable the delivery of copybooks static structures which were redefined before delivery. I was thinking of using xsd:redefine element potentially but that is not supported by the WSDL2Cobol compiler. Just curious as well would you propse xsd:redefine to handle such cases?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to COBOL redefines clause; no, you cannot use xsd:redefine since it doesn't match the semantics (the best one for me is a choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I was setting up a test bed (Eclipse, ApacheV6, Axis2) and was running a test:

- Having a client which was using WSDL java bindings of V1 of the server (two choice elements)
- Having a server running with WSDL V2 implementation having three choices.
- Result: Java client could still connect and getting correct results for the two choice elements back from the V2 server (no marshalling problem, no recompile necessary).

Comment: What happened with the third choice?

Comment: I have to be more specific here:
The web service consumer/client with its V1 interface is passing in as input parameter that he either wants the data stored in _choice element 1_ or _choice element 2_. Both requests executed against der V2 provider interface will return either _choice element 1_ or _choice element 2_. So the server logic V1 didn't change only the server logic would now (for consuming clients of V2) pass back the _choice element 3_ (in case such a client pass in its input request this information). So the _choice element 3_ is transparent to V1 interface consumer.

Answer (score 1):

By a strict definition, I would call this a breaking change. By "strict", I mean that it's possible to write a program which will work before the change, and break after the change. Any program that would have received one of the two original choices before the change, but now will receive the third choice - this program will be broken.

Furthermore, any program which can read the WSDL will see that it changed. Such a program could reasonably be permitted to "break" if the WSDL changes.

Keep in mind that, when using a tool like wsdl2java or "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio, code is being written from the WSDL. A change in the WSDL will result in a change in the generated code. Don't take it lightly that you could be changing someone's code without their knowledge.

Comment: Hi John thx for the answer. By strict definition you are right.
In my real case the consumers will have to pass in a input param to the operation (an enum) in which he has to tell which choice element he wants to fetch. That means such a consumer will never be aware and will never get back the third choice element, due to the fact that in its java binding the choice element enum selector only allows the selection of the V1 choice elements. In case he wants to request the third choice element, he has to incorporate the extended WSDL (wsdl2java etc.) and do the code changes.